# WebDriverException... moveto did not match a known command

Tags: selenium-webdriver

When the Mouse Over Keyword is called I get the following error :

> WebDriverException: Message :POST /session/bcb99bc5-1b47-4438-b1b7-471785ea34c8/moveto did not match a known command on Mozilla FireFox(geckodriver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question:**WebDriverException: Message :POST /session/bcb99bc5-1b47-4438-b1b7-471785ea34c8/moveto did not match a known command on Mozilla FireFox(geckodriver)

**Answer:**Selenium web driver should be updated version and Firefox latest version will not supports the old selenium web driver,Firefox version should be 49.0 and selenium web driver version should be 3.0,then that issue will not come while executing the script.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly this appears to be a bug in the Mozilla/geckodriver side of the Actions implementation that has been lingering since mid 2016.  If you really need this, switch to something not Firefox or grab a pre-geckodriver Firefox (47 or below, I believe) and use the older webdriver bindings (i.e., Selenium 2).  Unfortunately, it is not as easy as just getting the older FF version.

See :
[Bugzilla bug report][1]
[Gecko bug report][2]

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1292178
  https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/159

Comment: PS, I deleted the selenium HQ bug report since it wouldn't let me post > 2 links.  https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2285